# Calculator opens every time I do a left click

Tags: ubuntu-mate

I use Ubuntu Mate 18.04.
Every time I do a left-click on my mouse mate-calculator starts up. I did nothing and how can I prevent this ? [Here](https://www.reddit.com/r/softwaregore/comments/9urrb1/thank_you_ubuntu_mate/?st=JO65TSWX&sh=cc4c46a1) is what happens to me.

I use Compiz if this matters

**EDIT:** The issue was my mouse which does not work anymore.

Comment: What menu pops up if you right-click the open desktop (i.e. wallpaper)?

Comment: @ZeissIkon No menu is opening when I righr-click the desktop. Usually it works

Comment: Have you carefully checked your keyboard for stuck keys?

Comment: @ZeissIkon Yes, it also happens when I unplug my keyboard

Comment: @N0rbert I'm not able to run a terminal, everytime I left click mate-terminal in my dock the calculator starts up. The only way to access the command line is via the tty

Comment: @N0rbert The output was exaclty what you have described

Comment: @N0rbert Yes, the issue was my mouse the keybindings chnaged absolutely

Comment: I cleaned out my comments above and summarized our debugging process in the answer. You may want to remove your comments above. You can accept it to help future readers :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We have had long debugging session. All software components were set correctly.

So the output of

```
gsettings list-recursively | grep mate-calc
```

was empty. And

```
gsettings get org.mate.SettingsDaemon.plugins.media-keys calculator
```

returned

```
'XF86Calculator'
```

as expected.

Resetting mouse settings in MATE did not help:

```
gsettings reset-recursively org.mate.peripherals-mouse
gsettings reset-recursively org.mate.SettingsDaemon.plugins.mouse
dconf reset -f /org/mate/desktop/accessibility/
```

The Compiz Settings Manager (launched with `ccsm` command) do not have *Button1*, *Button2* and *Button3* mentioned in *General* → *Commands* and on *Button Bindings* tab.

But `xev` output was weird, it did not show `ButtonPress` and `ButtonRelease` as reaction on press and release of mouse buttons.

---

**So it was a hardware issue.**